# Why object a is not in current context?

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public void method1()
        { }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public void method2()
        { }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.method1();    
    }
}
```

Please paste this code in VS and Please explain me why it is not in current context?

Comment: You've written statements at the class level, that's not allowed. You need to put the statements inside a method in the `Test` class. `A a = new A();` is legal because it declares a field with the default (private) accessibility modifier. `a.method1();` is not, however, since that is a statement, and you can't write statements at the class level.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a class is not the right place to call most functions:

```
public class Test
{
    A a = new A();
   a.method1();
}
```

Just put stuff into the main function, wich is there **specifically** for that part of the programming:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a = new A();
    a.method1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not have statements directly in class.

```
public class Test
{
    A a = new A();
    a.method1();     // this is not possible.
}
```

please modify your class as below:

```
public class Test
    {

        public void InvokeMethodOnA()
        {
             A a = new A();
             a.method1();    
        }
    }
```

or like this;

```
public class Test
{
    A a = new A();
    public void InvokeMethodOnA()
    {        
         a.method1();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call method in body of method (sounds strange, but I don't have a better explanation).

In your case you mix a definition of the class Test with a context of function. I hope code with comments will be more descriptive:

```
public class Test
{
    // this is not a local variable, this is a definition of field with initialization
    A a = new A();
    // you try call method on field, but in context of class definition, which is prohibited
    a.method1();
}
```